# Is it possible to distribute and iOS app without the having the source code

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store, ios-app-signing

*Short version*

Is it still possible for one developer to compile an iOS app and pass it to another who has the distribution certificate (and private key) to upload to App Store Connect?

*Background*

My company has signed a contract for an external developer to deliver an app for us to put into the app stores, without giving us the source code.

We have tried resigning the app by removing the _CodeSignature folder and running 'codesign -f -s  ......', but App Store Connect rejects it because of some problem with SwiftSupport folder. So now this external developer is insisting there is no way for him to compile the app and us to distribute it and wants our cert and private key even though Apple says "[Do not share Apple Certificates outside of your organization.](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/)"

Comment: Apple does not support re-signing .ipa files. You need at least the .xcarchive. Check this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/94151

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but a couple comments... Take a look at [Apple Developer Program Roles](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/) ... You can make the developer a Team Member, with permissions to submit the app. Sounds like a risky proposition though.... suppose there is a problem with the app? Apple will come after you, not your "external developer" ... as well as potential issues down the road when you want/need to make updates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Check out this tool on github https://github.com/Elyorbe/XReSign